# Product of cycles of length $n$

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory

Let $n = 2k$ and suppose that $\sigma$ is a permutation in $S_n$ which is equal to a product of k disjoint cycles of length $2$. In how many ways one can write $\sigma$ as a product of two cycles of length $n$? Clearly when $k$ is odd the number is zero. So we can assume that $k$ is even.

Comment: Not sure if the votes to close are justified, looks like a reasonable question to me. Maybe the OP could tell us why he is interested in his question.

Comment: It will depend on the cycle type of $\sigma$. You could in principal calculate it for any given cycle type from the character table of $S_n$. (I also don't understand the votes to close.)

Comment: @RichardStanley your post is missing a link :(

Comment: @Derek Holt: I understand the question that $\sigma$ is a product of $k$ disjoint transpositions.

Comment: That's not what the question says, it says $k$ disjoint cycles, which could for example mean one of length $5$ and $3$ of length $1$ when $k=4$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry, But what I had in mind was $k$ cycles of length 2. I will edit my post.

Comment: One place (of several) where this problem is discussed is http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/47.pdf. See Theorem 3.1. A further reference (with many additional references) is https://math.uwaterloo.ca/math/sites/ca.math/files/uploads/files/GNicaJCTA2005.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

A closely related [paper of Don Zagier's.](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/tex/CyclesOfElemsSymmGroups/fulltext.pdf)